# multiple before/after blocks in Scala BeforeAndAfter

Tags: scala, scalatest

Can scalatest support mulitple before and after blocks?

If so what would be the order of execution?

```
trait A extends BeforeAndAfter {
val aa

before {
  // access aa
}

after {
  // access aa
}
}

class B with A {
val bb

before {
  // access bb
}

after {
  // access bb
}
}
```

EDIT: base on one of the answers, it's not possible. Wonder how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Why not just try the code for yourself? Running this snippet

```scala
trait A extends TestSuite with BeforeAndAfter {
  before {
    // First call
  }

  before {
    // Second call
  }
}
```

Results in

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.NotAllowedException: 
You are only allowed to call before once in each Suite that mixes in BeforeAndAfter.
```

Same goes for `after`. The answer is no, **you are not allowed to call `before` or `after` more than once in any given `Suite` instance**. Note that using `A` and `B` is irrelevant here.